# Problema con transacciones en Mongoose y NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, backend, transacciones

Les comento, estoy aprendiendo hace poco NodeJS y estoy haciendo algunos ejercicios. Actualmente estoy viendo el manejo de transacciones en NodeJS y no puedo hacer que funcione, tengo el siguiente código:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports.create = async function (req, res) {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    try {
        let user = new User();
        user.rut = 'XXXXXXXX-X';
        user.name = 'Juan';
        user.lastname = 'Soto';
        await user.save();

        let user2 = new User();
        user2.name = 'Pedro';
        user2.lastname = 'Toledo';
        await user2.save();

        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();

        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();

        return false;
    }
};
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, el primer usuario se guarda en la BD, pero el segundo usuario provoca una caída y se ejecuta el catch ya que no estoy definiendo el parámetro **rut**, por ende al caer en el catch se ejecuta **await session.abortTransaction();**, pero si veo la BD Mongo el primer usuario sigue guardado, se supone que debería deshacer cualquier cambio en la BD. No se que puedo estar haciendo mal.

La conexión a la BD Mongo la tengo definida de esta forma:
**mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db_usuarios", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });**

Las versiones que ocupo son las siguientes:
NodeJS: 18.14.0 -
Mongoose: 6.7.3 -
Mongo DB: 6.0.5

Si me pudieran ayudar por favor!

Gracias...